# SQLRPGLE cursor returns properly when sorting by ASC order but returns nothing when ordered by DESC, Why?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am coding in IBM RDI and running the program on the 5250 emulator. I am writing a simple program reading from a single SQL table and the outputting results to a printer file. The code works basically as expected but I encountered something strange. When I try to sort my cursor select statement by desc order, it returns empty, but when i dont order by or when i order by ASC it works fine. I don't understand what is happening. I would really like an explanation.

Code below.

```
       DCL-F BOOKRPT2 PRINTER OFLIND(*IN01);

       DCL-S INDGENRE BINDEC(4:0);
       DCL-S CATEGORY CHAR(30);
       DCL-S TOTALRECORDS PACKED(5:0);
       DCL-S TOTALCOST ZONED(5:2);
       DCL-S EOF   IND;
       DCL-S DUMMY ZONED(1);

       DCL-DS BOOKRECORD;
         BOOK CHAR(50);
         DURATION TIME(*ISO);
         AUTHOR CHAR(30);
         BOOKID ZONED(7:0);
         PRICE PACKED(5:2);
         GENRE CHAR(20);
       END-DS;
       //DCL-DS AUDIBLEBKS EXT END-DS;
        //**************************************************************************
        //*                        ***   M A I N   R O U T I N E   ***
        //**************************************************************************
        EXSR PREPFILES;
        EXSR GETSYS;
        WRITE TITLE;
        WRITE COLHDG;
        EXSR GETROW;
        WRITE GENREREC;
        CATEGORY = GENRE;
        DOW NOT EOF;

        IF *IN01 = *ON;
           WRITE TITLE;
           WRITE COLHDG;

          *IN01 = *OFF;
        ENDIF;
          IF CATEGORY = GENRE;
            WRITE DETAIL;
            TOTALRECORDS +=1;
            TOTALCOST += PRICE;
         ELSE;

           WRITE TOTALS;
           CATEGORY = GENRE;
           WRITE GENREREC;
           TOTALRECORDS = 0;
           TOTALCOST = 0;
          ENDIF;
           TOTALBOOKS = TOTALRECORDS;
           TOTALPRICE = TOTALCOST;
        EXSR GETROW;
        ENDDO;
        WRITE TOTALS;
        EXSR WRAPUP;
        *INLR = *ON;
        RETURN;

       BEGSR PREPFILES;
         EXEC SQL
         DECLARE BOOKCURSOR  CURSOR
           FOR
            SELECT BOOK, DURATION, AUTHOR, BOOKID, PRICE, GENRE
            FROM BCI433LIB/AUDIBLEBKS
             ORDER BY GENRE DESC;
         //FOR READ ONLY;
           EXEC SQL
             OPEN  BOOKCURSOR;
                 IF SQLCODE <> 0 OR SQLWN0='W';
                   EOF = *ON;
                 ENDIF;
       ENDSR;

        BEGSR GETROW;
          EXEC SQL
            FETCH NEXT
              FROM BOOKCURSOR
              INTO :BOOKRECORD;
           IF SQLCODE <> 0 OR SQLWN0 = 'W';
              EOF = *ON;
            ENDIF;
        ENDSR;

        BEGSR WRAPUP;
           EXEC SQL
               CLOSE BOOKCURSOR;

             IF SQLCODE <> 0  OR SQLWN0 ='W';
               EOF = *ON;
             ENDIF;
        ENDSR;

        BEGSR GETSYS;
         EXEC SQL
         SELECT CURRENT SERVER, CURRENT DATE
           INTO :SYSTEMNAME, :REPORTDATE
         from SYSIBM/SYSDummy1;
        ENDSR;
```

[image: No Order By]

[image: with DESC order By]

Comment: what are the `SQLCODE` and/or `SQLSTATE` values after you open the cursor?  They may tell you what's going on.

Comment: yeah I know how to check them for errors while the program runs and respond accordingly with select and if cases, but I do not know how to go about manually checking what the sqlcode/state is while the program is running.
do you mean with srtdbg mode?

Comment: anyway you chose, personally I usually explicitly check for no-data and for other non-zero log the returned SQLSTATE before ending.

Comment: this is what i did in my code
    IF SQLCODE <> 0 OR SQLWN0 = 'W';
              EOF = *ON;
            ENDIF;

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the code formatting issues, the most likely answer I see is that you have an issue with the last record in the query when you sort by `ASC` but its the first record when you sort by `DESC`.  As other answers have stated, that should be easily checked by looking at `SQLSTATE`.  The quickest way to do that would be to simply run it in the RDi debugger or through `STRDBG`.

Comment: But the query works fine in  interactive sql outside program, I made the collection myself so I know the data is fine. My prof said that when using a cursor we only check sqlWn and sqlcode, is he wrong ? cause I wont be surprised if he is. He was only showing us to check sqlstate when using simple non cursor queries.

Comment: Yes he's wrong.  You don't need to check both SQLCOD and SQLSTATE.  You only need to check one of them and SQLSTATE is the standard these days.  SQLCOD is technically depracated but IBM has stated they have no plans to remove it at this time.  There is also no need to check SQLWN0 either.  If might make it slightly more convenient to find out a particular error if its one of those 11 indicators but if you are just checking if SQLWN0 is set to 'W', you can skip that whole thing and just check SQLSTATE as well.  As it stands, I think each indicator in SQLWN has a particular SQLSTATE value.

Comment: wow Yeah I am not surprised at all everything we learned has been out of date in this class. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you should check SQL State, but I ignore warnings. There is a good chance that the last line in your cursor is causing a warning, not an error. So STRSQL would show the records, but since you are blowing up on the warning (but not indicating what it might be) you don't get anything.

Here is the error checking code I put after virtually every SQL statement in my programs.

```
exec sql
  ...
if %subst(sqlstate: 1: 2) < '00' or %subst(sqlstate: 1: 2) > '02';
  exec sql get diagnostics condition 1
    :message = message_test;
  SendSqlMsg(message);
endif;
```

Some explaination here message is a varchar(6000) and SendSqlMsg() is a sub-procedure I wrote to send an escape message.

Further note about SQLSTATE classes (first 2 characters of SQLSTATE):

- 00 - Normal completion
- 01 - Warnings
- 02 - No data

Everything else is an error.

One more note, I said I put this after virtually every SQL statement, but I do not check it after a close cursor. Here is the reason for that. The only state that `CLOSE` throws is "the cursor is already closed". I don't care if a close cursor failed for this reason since I want the cursor closed, and it is closed, no problem.

Comment: this is a great answer thank you I am going to test it out and see what happens! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your program should always check SQLSTATE and have code to handle abnormal SQLSTATE values.  It could be writing to the joblog, sending an email alert, etc.

```
If SQLSTATE <> '00000'; // sucess
  // handle abnormal condition
Endif;
```

If you can't/won't change the code, use RDi to debug the code and check the SQLSTATE after each operation.

Comment: So my prof when teaching showed us that we only check sqlstate when using non cursor queries, and told us when using a cursor to check sqlWN and sqlcode. Is he incorrect? and what is really weird is that if make the query outside of the program in interactive sql, it returns properly and shows what i expect.

Comment: He is incorrect.  Getting different results between STRSQL and an SQLRPGLE is not unheard of.  It likely stems from differences in environment (e.g. *LIBL) and the SQL settings.  In STRSQL, you can press F13 and then take the "Change session attributes" option.   For SQLRPGLE, use DSPPGM command and use "5=Display description" on the module, then page down for the SQL info.  I still say check the SQLSTATE and look it up here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzala/rzalaccl.htm